# master detail project template and canDisplayBannerAds not working

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller, iad

For my working project, I am trying to add iAd banner using canDisplayBannerAds but it seems to be not working.

To test the things, I created a new master detail application and just added iAd framework, and written `splitViewController?.canDisplayBannerAds = true` in viewDidLoad() method. Results are in the screenshots.

How can I fix the master view controller grey screen?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iAd network will soon be discontinued and new apps are no longer accepted. You might want to reconsider.
https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=01152016a